# Rep Score different between top bar and "Your Communities" drop down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Not a big deal obviously... But I answered a question today and then opened the drop down, and under the "Your Communities" section the rep didn't update. Is this by design (updated periodically), or a bug?  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rep value in either of these is taken from different places.

In the top bar - directly from your user record, which should be as up to date as possible.

In the communities drop down - from the aggregated network user record, where we collect the values from users across the network. This is not real-time but gets updated on a schedule (and only when things change - like reputation, badges and so on).

So, there is a short window of time when these could be out of sync.