# Rep-tab and rep-window apparently don't agree with each other

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I've noticed something weird that's been happening for the past 30 minutes or so. An answer of mine to a particular question had been received reasonably well (with 6 votes), however, the score does not register on the reputation tab.

I've taken two screenshots at exactly the same time, and they should be pretty self explanatory:

[image]

Contrast this with:

[image]

You can see that, in the rep-window, the +60 rep I'd received from the aforementioned answer registered in the rep tab, but not the rep window. Every other notification appears to be mirrored perfectly, with just the +60 missing, nothing else.

What I find even more peculiar is the fact that I had received all the upvote notifications in the form of +10s, but no entry was shown or highlighted.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

---

Edit: Here's a full display of my achievements tab, the notification does not show anywhere.

[image]
[image]

The title of the question that I've answered, *Intuition and idea behind reshaping 4D array to 2D array in NumPy* does not show anywhere here even though it shows in the rep-tab below.

Updating rep-tab display correspondingly -

[image]

Comment: I've removed my answer because a) I ran out of time to follow up properly and b) I may misread the situation. Given that it is the summary for today that appears out-of-sync, it may be an issue with the central network storage of that info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rep Score different between top bar and “Your Communities” drop down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326370/rep-score-different-between-top-bar-and-your-communities-drop-down)

Comment: @YohDeadfall Did you read the answers to that question? There's no way that approved edits are the reason for 60 rep going unaccounted for.

Comment: that's because your rep increase is impossible to follow :)

Comment: I wish that was the reason but I don't think it is :-(

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong link. Fixed.

Comment: @YohDeadfall Okay, a little more sensible, but that isn't even the right dropdown. Furthermore, I can understand why there would be discrepancies between those two scores, but I cannot see how that applies to this anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rep Score different between top bar and "Your Communities" drop down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326370/rep-score-different-between-top-bar-and-your-communities-drop-down)

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361096/rep-tab-and-rep-window-apparently-dont-agree-with-each-other?noredirect=1#comment542603_361096 My reply to the last guy who suggested the same thread as dupe. If you can explain _how_ they are similar, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Notifications in the drop down stored separately from the history. Therefore, they probably are out of sync due to caching.

Comment: @YohDeadfall That would make sense for the dropdown you refer to, but I don't know if the same applies to the achievements dropdown, the two are very different, and the latter has always been in sync with the rep tab (I've never had reason to believe otherwise). I don't think this can be explained away by a simple status-bydesign, only a SO employee can really say anything with authority here.